# Killing cohomology of structure sheaf by pullback along Frobenius and finite etale covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, etale-covers

On a smooth projective variety $X$ over a finite field, you can pullback any element in $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ by a combination of Frobenius and finite etale cover so it gets killed. In order to prove it I consider an element $\alpha$ in the cohomology group. This corresponds to an extension of $\mathcal{O}_X$ by itself. Since this cohomology group is finite and Frobenius acts on it, there is some $n$ and $m$ ($m>n$) such that $F^{*n}\alpha=F^{*m}\alpha$. By [Prop 2.3](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2008/0015/0006/MRL-2008-0015-0006-a003.pdf) this means that you can pullback the extension $F^{*n}\alpha$ so it becomes a trivial vector bundle. Now the short exact sequence corresponding to $F^{*n}\alpha$ consists of three trivial vector bundles so it splits. This means pullback of $F^{*n}\alpha$ to some finite etale cover is trivial.

My question: is it possible to kill elements in $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ by a combination of pullback along Frobenius and finite etale covers? ($1<i<dim(X)$)

Comment: yes you can. look at the paper of Hochster and Huneke for a generalisation: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183556250

Comment: This seems like an expository paper. I'm not sure whether by finite and surjective they mean what I mean. I specifically require it to be a composition of Frobenius and finite etale covers.

Comment: Take an ordinary smooth projective Calabi-Yau hypersurface $X \subset \mathbf{P}^{n+1}$ of big dimension (probably $n\geq 2$ is enough). Then $X$ will be simply connected as $n$ is big, so finite etale covers are useless. Ordinarity means the Frobenius acts bijectively on the $1$-dimensional vector space $H^n(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, so that doesn't help either.

Comment: I see so $i=dim(X)$ is problematic.

Comment: This has little to do with whether $i$ equals $\dim X$, as you can take a product of any of these with $\mathbf P^N$. I think that already gives counterexamples for each $i \geq 2$ in each dimension $d \geq i$.

Comment: Name of the linked paper (referenced for "Prop 2.3"):  [Brenner and Kaid - On deep Frobenius descent and flat bundles](https://doi.org/10.4310/MRL.2008.v15.n6.a3).  @ali's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381952/killing-cohomology-of-structure-sheaf-by-pullback-along-frobenius-and-finite-eta#comment971007_381952):  [Hochster and Huneke - Absolute integral closures are big Cohen–Macaulay algebras in characteristic $P$](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1991-15970-7).